How to Align Icon to the Right in Blender Panel Header using python?
I’m trying to customize a panel using python in Blender 4.1, and I want to align an icon to the right side of the panel header. (like this)

I’ve tried a few approaches, but I can’t seem to get it right. Could someone please provide an example on how to achieve this? Would be very helpful, thanks a lot !

use draw_header_preset()
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html#bpy.types.Panel.draw_header_preset
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Test"
    
    def draw_header_preset(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="", icon="INFO")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Thank you very much, it works!
That was my case, by the way:
``def draw_header(self, context):
layout = self.layout
layout.prop(context.scene.my_tool, "showhide_shake", text="")
def draw_header_preset(self, context):
layout = self.layout
infoRow = layout.row(align=True)
infoRow.operator("custom.show_message", icon="INFO", text="", emboss=False)``
